# Outlook Web Add-In - Design issue with height attribute

Tags: html, outlook-web-addins

I am developing a outlook web add-in project which reads a HTML template and inserts into a body of the new meeting when I click the add-in icon.

Below is the sample HTML which is similar to the template what I am using.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Some Text
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 200px; height: 50px">
                    &nbsp;<br />&nbsp;
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Actually height property is not working. Because of the that I am using "&nbsp". The template is rendered properly as expected with this design. But if the user press the backspace in the second column, design gets collapsed.

So anyone please suggest an idea to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the client and the build number you are facing this issue on? Windows Desktop Outlook, Outlook for Web or Outlook for Mac?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your issue. I am finding the following. 1) i am assuming you are using the body.setAsync method with html coercion type, right? 2) what do you mean by backspace?  you mean effectively removing the <br> element in your cell? can you please add a few screenshots to clarify your request? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook for Windows uses Microsoft Word to render the body of messages. Word does not support all possible HTML combinations, which is causing your template to render incorrectly. We suggest designing any templates in Word, then using the outputted HTML for your templates to ensure that it renders correctly in Outlook.